# Стили CSS в Django перестали работать

Tags: css, django

Я учу Django и столкнулся с проблемой, что если я удалю что-нибудь из файла styles.css или добавлю, ничего не изменится. Даже если удалить все содержание файла и перезапустить сервер ничего не поменяется. Файлы сохраняются автоматически.

layout.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.1.1/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'main/css/styles.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
    <aside>
        <img src="{% static 'main/img/logo.png' %}" alt="картинка всралась:(">
        <span class="logo">DoubleNut</span><br><br>
        <h3>Навигация</h3>
        <ul>
            <a href="{% url 'home' %}"><li><i class="fa-solid fa-house-chimney"></i> Главная</li></a>
            <a href="{% url 'about' %}"><li><i class="fa-solid fa-address-card"></i> О нас</li></a>
            <a href="{% url 'news_home' %}"><li><i class="fa-solid fa-newspaper"></i> Новости</li></a>
            <a href=""><li><i class="fa-solid fa-paper-plane"></i> Контакты</li></a>
        </ul>
    </aside>
    <main>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </main>

</body>
</html>
```

Настройки статических файлов в settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]
```

Comment: `ctrl + f5` в браузере пробовали?

Comment: Спасибо, работает!

Answer (score 0):

Обычно для STATICFILES_DIRS у меня такая запись. Работает безотказно)

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'path_to_static_dir')]
```